# Could this code be vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript

It seems like exploiting `XSS` is becoming harder with every browser version update.

My question is: Is this code vulnerable to `XSS`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = location.href;
    document.write("URL: " + url);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific code is unlikely to be vulnerable to XSS, but only because the URL in `href` was not decoded. For example, visiting `bad.html?x=<script>alert("xss")</script>` would write the following to to the page:

```
https://example.com/bad.html?x=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22xss%22)%3C/script%3E
```

This is because the `<`, `>`, and `"` characters are encoded as part of the URL.

However, if the javascript on the page was to pass `location.href` through the `decodeURI` function first, i.e. writing `decodeURI(location.href)`, it would be vulnerable. The following would be written to the document:

```
https://example.com/bad.html?x=<script>alert("xss")</script>
```